# Sun-JRE on CentOS-4.8 RPM error: post-install scriptlet failed, exit status 5

Tags: centos, java, rpm, sun

I have a server with **CentOS 4.8** installed. The provided is rubbish, but there's only a few months left, and they're busy being sued by Chase bank, so I doubt I can get CentOS 5.

I wiped the server clean using Virtuozzo, and found that the default image is VERY empty. I even had to install yum myself.

I've reached the point where I want to install TomCat. I downloaded the Sun JRE as a .rpm.bin file, did chmod a+x and ran it. That produced a .rpm file, which I tried installing:

```
[root@host java]# rpm -Uvh jre-6u20-linux-i586.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jre                    ########################################### [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
    rt.jar...
    jsse.jar...
    charsets.jar...
    localedata.jar...
    plugin.jar...
    javaws.jar...
    deploy.jar...
error: %post(jre-1.6.0_20-fcs.i586) scriptlet failed, exit status 5
[root@host java]# rpm -qi jre
Name        : jre                          Relocations: /usr/java 
Version     : 1.6.0_20                          Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Release     : fcs                           Build Date: Mon Apr 12 19:34:13 2010
Install Date: Thu May  6 06:36:17 2010      Build Host: jdk-lin-1586
Group       : Development/Tools             Source RPM: jre-1.6.0_20-fcs.src.rpm
Size        : 50708634                         License: Sun Microsystems Binary Code License (BCL)
Signature   : (none)
Packager    : Java Software <jre-comments@java.sun.com>
URL         : http://java.sun.com/
Summary     : Java(TM) Platform Standard Edition Runtime Environment
Description :
The Java Platform Standard Edition Runtime Environment (JRE) contains
everything necessary to run applets and applications designed for the
Java platform. This includes the Java virtual machine, plus the Java
platform classes and supporting files.

The JRE is freely redistributable, per the terms of the included license.
[root@host java]#
```

I couldn't find any results on Google for any parts of that error message, and I have very little experience of rpm (I usually use Debian).

Is this a broken package, or am I missing something or some setting?

Comment: I finaly found this: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6490650 which suggests a problem with binfmt_misc when running in a Virtuozzo environment... Now trying to work out how to fix that!

Comment: Note that running `rpm -q` with modifiers other than `-p` takes the package *name*, not the package filename.

Comment: Thanks. I did rpm -evv jre to erase it and try again, but the same scriptlet error occurred.

Comment: I've now removed the RPM attempt, and tried the plain .bin version. navigating to the new folder and running ./java gives: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Cannot create VM thread. Out of system resources.
I think it's time for an up-to-date host!

Comment: I doubt this question is still alive...

Answer (score 1):

You might find it helpful to inspect the postinstall scriptlet that is actually failing.  Try the following:

```
rpm -q --scripts -p jre-6u20-linux-i586.rpm
```

That will display all the scriptlets in the rpm file.  There may be a spelling or path mistake in the jre's postinstall scriptlet.  You can inspect it visually and manually run it using the shell it specifies (cut/paste the contents of the scriptlet into a script file and run it manually).

Comment: I tried splitting the post-install script into a separate file; it appears some of the packed JARs are removed later in the process so when I do rpm -Uvh jre... then ./postinstall.sh it can't find the missing .jar.pack files. No other errors though.